# Symfony createQueryBuilder with many to many

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my system candidate and profession has many to many relationship. I need to implement following query in symfony.

```
SELECT c. *
FROM candidate AS c
LEFT JOIN candidate_profession AS cp ON cp.candidate_id=c.id
WHERE cp.profession_id = 2
```

So i wrote following code.

```
$matched = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Candidate')
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.professions = :profession')
             ->setParameter('profession', $job->getProfession())
             ->getQuery()
             ->getResult();
```

`$job->getProfession()` is return profession object. But it show following error.

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 51 near 'professions =': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

How i implement that query?

Answer (score 1):

I think your query should look like this:

```
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Candidate')
    ->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->leftJoin('c.professions', 'p')
    ->where('p.id = :profession')
    ->setParameter('profession', $job->getProfession())
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

More about join clauses: http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#join-clauses

Comment: No, this isn't the right answer at all. Error is into `setParameter` not into query structure

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, I don't know where you have placed that snippet of code but I strongly advice you to migrate it into a [Repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) if you don't have already done (but looking at code I'm not sure you have)

**Second**, you need to pass an ID as `->getProfession()` (as you already noticed) will return the whole object and you don't need it

So your query should be like this

```
$matched = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Candidate')
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.professions = :profession')
            ->setParameter('profession', $job->getProfession()->getId())
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

#### Please pay attention

You didn't specify the cardinality of relationship between job and profession: if is a *something-to-Many* you can't simply use `->getId()` as returned object is an `ArrayCollection`, so, in that case, you need to do a loop to extract all id(s) and then use something like "IN" clause

Comment: My repository is correct. I have tried it also. ($job->getProfession()->getId()) But it is showing same error. $job->getProfession()->getId() return value as 3. So it also has no issue.